# Quiero pasar un parametro a una etiqueta HTML con PHP

Tags: php, html5

```
'<?php  $funct1= "onclick=showCustomer(".$codigo.  ")";  ?>'

'<div id="mias3" class="btn btn-default" <?php $funct1   ?>  > '
```

esto es lo que quiero hacer, pero no funciona.

¿Qué se recomienda en estos casos.?

Answer (score 2):

Según la especificación html 4.01, un <div> es un contenedor y sirve para dar estructura, por ello, para hacer 'click' en un <div>, este no debe estar vacío, o sea que se hace click en el *contenido* del div y no en el div como tal. Como no muestras el código completo (y basándome en lo que muestras), una posible solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
<div id="mias3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showcustomer(<?php echo $codigo; ?>); "> 
    Click Aqui </button>
</div>

<script>
function showcustomer(i) {
    alert("Valor pasado = " + i);
}
</script>
```

Comment: A la etiqueta de cierre del script le faltó el '/'

Comment: Corregido, gracias.